# What is packageGroup in ng-update object?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I am doing analysis around ng-update command in angular to run custom logic after ng-update.

I came across an ng-update object's property `packageGroup` of which I did not find detailed explanation.

Explanation provided in angular docs -

> A list of npm packages that
> are to be grouped together. When running the update schematic it will
> automatically include all packages as part of the packageGroup in the
> update (if the user also installed them).

Link to the docs - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/specifications/update.md

Can anybody who have used it explain what it actually does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use `packageGroup` inside `ng-update` object of package.json and if we mention some dependencies inside `packageGroup`, then the ng update command will update the `packageGroup` packages with the same version as targeted by ng update command.

Example -

Suppose if you are running `ng update somePackage@5.0.0` and it's package.json contains `packageGroup` like below

```
{
  ...
  "ng-update": {
    "migrations": "./migrations.json",
    "packageGroup": [
      "package1",
      "package2",
      "package3"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

then after running ng update command, packages mentioned inside `packageGroup` will also get updated to 5.0.0 version as mentioned in ng update command.